# 6 finger Flute hole placement formula

Tags: flute, construction

I like to experiment on plastic flutes.
Is there a mathematical formula for placing holes in a flute?
Is it same for all kinds of flutes for example western flute,6 hole flute or 8 hole flute?

Comment: Yes there is - what scale, or intervals, do you want to be able to generate?   Do you want to be able to generate pitches in the overtone series?

Comment: Let's say I want to make an E scale 6 hole or eight hole flute. I know for present that an eight hole Indian flute can generate about 2 and a half octaves.

Comment: Two and a half octaves is a lot and requires overblowing. I'm somewhat sceptical, whether a non-expert player on a home-made instrument can achieve that.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 1 and a half octave.

Answer (score 6):

There are mathematical formulas for placing flute holes. You will need different ones for each different style of flute. A Google search for "flute hole calculator" turns up about ten sites that provide the calculations. Several good ones:

- [flutomat](http://iotic.com/flutomat/)
- [Bracker Whistles](https://www.music.bracker.uk/Music/Whistle-Calculator.html)
- a [description](https://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/fingers.html) of the calculations